# issue with bash : 2 variables instead of one

Tags: bash, sed

I've written this piece of code.

The aim is the following :

for each files in the temp list, it should take the first occurence of the list, put it into a variable called `$name1` and then the second occurence of the list into a second variable called `$name2`. The variables are file names. With the 2 variables, I do a join.

```
for files in $(cat temp.lst); do
 if [ $(cat temp.lst | wc -l) == 1 ]
  then 
   name=$(head -1 temp.lst)
   join -t\; -j 1 file_minus1.txt "$name" | sed 's/;;/;/g' > file1.txt
  else
   name1=$(head -1 temp.lst)
   name2=$(head -2 temp.lst)
   echo "var1 "$name1 "var2 "$name2
   sed '1,2d' temp.lst > tmpfile.txt
   mv tmpfile.txt temp.lst
   join -t\; -j 1 "$name1" "$name2" | sed 's/;;/;/g' > file_minus1.txt
  fi
;done
```

Theoretically, it should work but here it is not working, alas.

The `echo` line I've put in my code is giving me 3 variables instead of 2

```
var1 ei_etea17_m.tsv var2 ei_etea17_m.tsv ei_eteu25_m.tsv
```

Worse, the join is not functionning the way I thought, giving me this error code instead

```
join: ei_etea17_m.tsv
ei_eteu25_m.tsv: No such file or directory
```

Please find a sample of my `temp.lst`

```
ei_eteu27_m.tsv
ei_eteu28_m.tsv
ei_isbr_m.tsv
ei_isbu_m.tsv
ei_isin_m.tsv
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Best.

Comment: Two points:  1)Why are you using a for loop?  You're not using the $files variable but cat'ing the input file again to see how many lines it has.  The point of the for loop should be to work on one line at a time.  And 2) head -n returns the first n lines of the file, not the nth line, so head -2 temp.lst is not giving you what you want.

Comment: Hey Rojomoke, thanks for your feedback. Can you suggest something different than the loop? My aim is to parse sequentially my text file.  The `head -n`is doing what I'm expecting it to do e.g. retrieving the first line into variable `$name1`and the second line into variable `$name2`.

Comment: You said in your question that your echo command was returning three values.  That's because the second head command is returning two lines.  So var2 is `ei_etea17_m.tsv` _(1st line)_ `ei_eteu25_m.tsv` _(2nd line)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract 2 lines of a file in a loop, try this:

```
paste - - < temp.lst | 
while read name1 name2; do
    if [[ -z $name2 ]]; then
        name2=$name1
        name1=file_minus1.txt
        output=file1.txt
    else
        output=file_minus1.txt
    fi
    join -t\; "$name1" "$name2" | sed 's/;;/;/g' > $output
done
```

Notes

- the `paste` command takes 2 consecutive lines from the file and joins them into a single line (separated by tab)

  - demo: `seq 7 | paste - -`
- `read` can assign to multiple variables: the line will be split on whitespace (default) and assigned to the named variables.
- in the loop body, I basically follow your logic

Comment: Thanks Glenn for your help. Let me have a look at your solution.

Comment: Your `while` is more elegant than my `for`. Can you explain a bit more , please? I'm just a perpetual clueless kind of newbie who is always asking questions.

Comment: Note that a `for x in $stuff` iterates over the **words** in $stuff. When reading from a file or from stdin, you generally want to read a line at a time, so the `while read line` idiom is preferred.

Comment: Note2: to read a file line-by-line completely safely: `while IFS= read -r line; do ...` -- that does not accidentally drop leading/trailing whitespace, and it does not interpret control chars or escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks Glenn for your explanations.

Comment: Glenn, thanks again for your explanations. What you did is great, very elegant and not clumsy like what I did.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

To perform an `n`-way join, use recursion :)

```sh
recursive_join () {
    # Zero files: do nothing (special case)
    # One file: output it
    # Multiple files: join the first with the result of joining the rest
    file1=$1
    shift || return
    [ "$#" -eq 0 ] && cat "$file1" ||
      recursive_join "$@" | join -t\; -j1 "$file1" -
 }

 recursive_join ei_eteu27_m.tsv ei_eteu28_m.tsv ei_isbr_m.tsv ei_isbu_m.tsv ei_isin_m.tsv
```

Adapting this to use a file listing the input files, rather than using command-line arguments, is a little tricker. As long as none of the input file names contain whitespace or other special characters, you could simply use

```
recursive_join $(cat temp.lst)
```

Or, if you want to avail yourself of `bash` features, you could use an array:

```
while read; do files+=("$REPLY"); done < temp.lst
recursive_join "${files[@]}"
```

or in `bash` 4:

```
readarray files < temp.list
recursive_join "${files[@]}"
```

However, if you want to stick with standard shell scripting only, it would be better to modify the recursive function to read the input file names from standard input. This makes the function a little uglier, since in order to detect if there is only one file left on standard input, we have to try to read a second one, and put it back on standard input if we succeed.

```
recursive_join () {
    IFS= read -r file1 || return
    IFS= read -r file2 &&
       { echo "$file2"; cat; } | recursive_join  | join -t\; -j1 "$file1" - ||
       cat "$file1"
}

recursive_join < temp.lst
```

Creating a function that can take *either* command-line arguments or read a list from standard input is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Variable name1 is getting the first line.
Variable name2 is getting the first two lines.
If you want name2 to have only the second line you could try something like:

```
name2=$(sed -n '2p')
```

Also sed -i will remove the need for tmpfile.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Gents or Ladies.

I found out the Why.

`head -1 temp.lst` is only given the file name without the extension.

I need to find a way to include the extension. Doable.